# achartengine-0.6.0 library barchart android

Tags: android, jar, achartengine, bar-chart

**Hello Friends,**

I have download `achartengine-0.6.0` for implement bar-chart,I have lots of r&d on it. but not find out class for **bar-chart**. can you tell me that how can I implement **bar-chart** with using this **library**?

Any **Example** in your mind?

**Thanks

nik**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to start with AChartEngine is to follow the instructions [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) in order to import the "official" demo program. That has a lot of code examples, including for bar charts.

Also, please note that intermediate releases for both the library and the demo program are published [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/download.html).